# Generate extent report using "ITestListener" or "IReporter" listeners

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports

**I need to generate a `testng extent report (version 3)`. I saw that there are two ways to generate an extent report.**

Here, I am explaining two cases without using the code.

> - Case 1:
>
>   Creating a class implementing "IReporter" listener and this class is defined in the testng.xml file.
> - Case 2:
>
>   Creating a java class (ExtentTestManager.java) and defined relavent methods, used "com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest" and "com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports" packages for implementation the logics.

Then, creating a class (TestListener) implementing "ITestListener" listener and extending BaseTest Class.

To override methods, this class is used the methods in ExtentTestManager.java class. Finally, this new class is defined testng.xml file.

Here, I want to know which implementation is appropriate to generate an extent report and reasons, please.

In case 2, why should be "TestListener" class extended the "TestBase" class as well?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for this question. Please refer this article.

https://medium.com/extent-report-3-1-5-itestlistener-implementation/extent-report-is-widely-used-as-html-report-for-selenium-test-scripts-reason-being-simple-its-3f19214b2e19